# Woocommerce I want product to be available in specific months only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the product to be available in specific months only. I created advance custom field checkbox field to check the months in which product will be available, using *"[Display a custom message when a product is not purchassable in Woocommerce single pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427175/display-a-custom-message-when-a-product-is-not-purchassable-in-woocommerce-singl/55430607#55430607)"* answer code to one of my previous questions and it does show and hide and add to cart button depending on the month set…

But the problem is that when it's available (showing the add to cart button) and we click on it, it says you cannot purchase this product. How to avoid that?

Comment: I have tested the code under last Woocommerce version 3.7 on storefront theme and everything works perfectly, when product is available, clicking on the add to cart button does add the product to cart and there is no message saying that: "You cannot purchase this product"… or something similar. So There is something else that making trouble: It can be another customization made by you, the theme or a plugin...

Comment: I installed the new wordpress and just only installed woocommerce and advanced custom field only and used storefront theme same as you did but I am getting this error. There is no extra script added be me and there is no other plugin activated except these two.